# Convergence or Divergence of an Improper Integral

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Is the following improper integral convergent or divergent? Why?
>   $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} \, dx.$$

I thought it would be divergent using the Comparison Theorem since the integral of $1/x^2$ from $0$ to $1$ would be divergent.

Comment: Your thoughts, please?

Comment: I thought it would be divergent using the Comparison Theorem since the integral of 1/x^2 from 0 to 1 would be divergent

Comment: Can't you use the Maclaurin expansion of $\cos(x)$?

Comment: @KentaS: that is pretty useless, since $\frac{1}{(2m)!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2m}}{x^2}\,dx $ is divergent.

Comment: On the other hand, you might use that $$\mathcal{L}(1-\cos x) = \frac{1}{s(1+s^2)},\qquad \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=s $$ to state $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s}{s(1+s^2)}\,ds = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$ The integral in the LHS is convergent by integration by parts: $1-\cos x$ has mean $1$ and behaves like $\frac{x^2}{2}$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Note that we can write the numerator of the integrand as: $1-\cos x =2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}$.

Now, studying the behaviour of $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}}{x^2} \,\text{ and } \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}}{x^2}$$ what can you conclude?

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Show that for $x>0$,
$$0\leq \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\leq \min\left (1,\frac{2}{x^2}\right).$$
Then use the Comparison Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

We note that this is closely tied to a related (and well known) integral with $\sin(x)$.
$$I'(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1-\cos(tx)}{x^2}\right)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(tx)}{x}dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \,(\forall t > 0)$$
Thus, after antidifferentiating, we find
$$I(t) = \frac{\pi}{2}t+C$$
Note that $C=0\,$ since we have $C = I(0) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(0x)}
{x^2}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} 0 \,dx = 0$.
Thus, in conclusion,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}dx = I(1) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
Note that these integral being tied should come as no surprise, since

$\lim_{x=0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2}\,$ and $\,\lim_{x=0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2} = 1\,$ are dual identities, as can be seen by looking at the Taylor Expansions of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ about $0$.

---

Worth mentioning that with the proper choice of indented contour (e.g. a semicircle with indent at the origin), we trivially get the value of the integral as
$$\frac{1}{2}\Re\left[\pi i\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2},0\right)\right] = \frac{1}{2}\Re\left[\pi i \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1-e^{iz}}{z}\right] = \frac{1}{2}\Re\left[\pi i (-i)\right] = \frac{\pi}{2}$$