# Why do I get the different graph?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, graphing-functions, real-numbers

[image]

Today I found an unusual thing. Aren't both expressions same?. but graph seems different at $x=0$. Why?. I was trying to answer the question. [Convergence or Divergence of an Improper Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562869/convergence-or-divergence-of-an-improper-integral). I noticed the difference accidentally. Please help me.

Comment: Yes, the two expressions are the same. Neither is defined at $0$, so they also don't differ at $0$. The graphing software is just getting bigger and bigger errors when calculating the values of the expression near $0$.

Comment: They are the same and IMO that is just a visualisation bug, as the function is not defined in 0. 
I got the same result as you did. Zoomed in/out and the bug vanished.

Comment: @P.Siehr Let me zoom the graph.